# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: android.support.v4.app.BackStackState[] of length 1279544898 would overflow

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

These crashes occur intermittently while backing into my main activity, which consists of two fragments (one being a Google Maps support fragment). If it wasn't for our crash-tracking system, I'd have no idea users were experiencing this, as it is not reproducible on any of my physical or emulated devices. It spans various APIs between my min of 15 and my target of 22.

In the crash system, the crash is occurring in one of two forms:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: android.support.v4.app.BackStackState[] of length 1279544898 would overflow
```

or

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5118179604 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 472MB until OOM near/at g.newArray:174
```

The crashing occurs in the onViewCreated method of the fragment containing my map:

```
mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

My first thought is memory leak, but...it looks like it's looping when creating the backstack -- as if the index of backstacks has overflowed the long. Leak Canary didn't find any memory leaks (except for our MainApplication, which I know retains a static reference to context). And if it WAS a typical memory leak, it seems odd this crash would always occur on the same line and nowhere else. There are other memory-intensive areas of this app (which is enterprise, so I can't divulge too much), but none of those other activities have thrown OOM errors.

I should also note that this is a mature app, with many users and releases. The OOM issue occurs ONLY in the beta of our current release (again, based solely on the records of our crash-tracking system, since we can't repro anywhere). I've done thorough code comparisons between our production release and our beta, and most of the changes are relatively standard/trivial. (I haven't started adding new bitmaps or anything.)

The specs:

- Play Services 8.4.0
- Gradle 2.1
- Target API 22
- Min API 15
- ProGuard enabled

Anyone else seeing this? I can see the crash is happening, but it's awfully hard to track down when I can't reproduce it...

Comment: add full onCreate code

Comment: It's enterprise code, so I can't. I tried to add all the relevant stuff I could without violating the policy.

Comment: then you shouldn't ask questions about it

Comment: I posted the answer already. I was just trying to create a record for future users to refer to in case they run into the same problem.

Comment: If someone is getting these same errors in logcat, the answer below may help them. My alternative was to post nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I was able to repro the error by enabled Don't Keep Activities in developer options.

After three days of testing, I eventually discovered that our build server was compiling support 24 instead of the support 22 I have specified in Gradle. Evidently there's some incompatibility between support 24 and android maps. By changing:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
```

to

```
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0') {
    force = true
}
```

thus forcing Gradle to take 22 instead of the later 24 available to it, the looping backstack went away. Now I'm no longer seeing the OOM with our beta users.

I speculate it has something to do with the permissions model change of API, but who knows.

Anyway...hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: We were using 8.4, though 9.2 is now available. See the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

Comment: We have this crash on google play services maps 9.0.2 and support version 24, so I was curious to see if this was a similar case

Comment: Interesting. The crash WAS caused by the use of support 24, which came in by mistake. We were targeting 22 and compiling with 24. Which API does your app target?

Comment: Hmm, I noticed now that we target API 22 and compiling API 24

Comment: That sounds similar to our scenario. Did you try forcing the support libraries to 22 (like the answer says...)?

Comment: I could, but according to the docs the support-library and compileSdkVersion version should be the same (could it cause other problems?)

Comment: Yes, they should be the same. If you're targeting API 22, you should include support for 22. But...Gradle will try to sneak in newer versions of the support library (if they're available on the machine) at compile time, unless you explicitly use the force tag. Normally that's no problem, because newer support libraries are generally backwards compatible, so you may not notice unless you look at the logs. But in this case, I unknowingly ended up compiling support 24, and it created this crash until I built 22 with the 'force' fix.

Comment: rolling back from 24.x.x to 23.4.0 or lower *fixes* this issue

Comment: What are the consequences of forcing support library 23.4.0 if I am targeting 24 ??